# What is the common way to throw exception if my exe file that i need to start does not exist on the machine

Tags: c#

in my application i am start capinfos.exe that is part of Wireshark.
in the constructor i am check if Wireshark install on the machine:

```
private string _filePath = "";

public Capinfos(string capturePath)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark"))
    {
        _capInfos = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\capinfos.exe";
    }
    else if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\Wireshark"))
    {
        _capInfos = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\capinfos.exe";
    }

    _filePath = capturePath;
}
```

what is the best way to do it and throw an exception if the file does not exist on the machine: please install Wireshark

Comment: _"in the constructor i am check if Wireshark install on the machine"_ - no you don't, you're checking if some exe exists in a hardcoded path. You should look at the registry to find the installation path (in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\wireshark.exe`) if you want this code to be portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private string _filePath = "";

public Capinfos(string capturePath) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark"))
    {
        _capInfos = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\capinfos.exe";
    }
    else if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\Wireshark"))
    {
        _capInfos = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\capinfos.exe";
    } else
    {
       throw new FileNotFoundException(@"Wireshark installation not found");
    } 

    _filePath = capturePath;
}
```

You can then catch the exception by using this code:

```
   try
    {
        Capinfos("path");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Messagebox.Show("Please install wireshark.");
    }
```

I don't have C# installed, this was written by hand. Hope it's fine!
Here's an excellent resource to learn on exceptions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: where to put the try - catch ?

Comment: Anywhere really, it's just a normal code block. You can put it in main, in the constructor, wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find " + _capInfos, _capInfos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but try to use a [try-catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) block. You could attempt to start the .exe in the try block and if it fails, throw a [FileNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception.aspx) and create a popup box in the catch block that will alert the user of what they need to do.